# services “kubernetes-dashboard” not found when accessing kubernetes UI interface

Tags: kubernetes

I followed the manual to install kubernetes dashboard.
Step 1:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" created
service "kubernetes-dashboard" created
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" created
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf" created
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder" created
configmap "kubernetes-dashboard-settings" created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" created
deployment.apps "kubernetes-dashboard" created
service "dashboard-metrics-scraper" created
The Deployment "dashboard-metrics-scraper" is invalid: spec.template.annotations.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: Invalid value: "runtime/default": must be a valid seccomp profile
```

Step 2:

```
kubectl proxy --port=6001 & disown
```

The output is -

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:6001
```

Now when I'm accessing the site -
http://localhost:6001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
it gives the following error -

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Also checking pods do not show kubernetes dashboard

```
kubectl get pod --namespace=kube-system
```

shows

```
NAME                                         READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-docker-for-desktop                      1/1       Running   0          13d
kube-apiserver-docker-for-desktop            1/1       Running   0          13d
kube-controller-manager-docker-for-desktop   1/1       Running   0          13d
kube-scheduler-docker-for-desktop            1/1       Running   0          13d.
```

.

```
kubectl get pod --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
```

returns-

```
NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard-659f6797cf-8v45l   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   15         1h
```

How to fix the problem ?

Update: The following link http://localhost:6001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services gives below output -

```
{
  "kind": "ServiceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services",
    "resourceVersion": "254593"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "dashboard-metrics-scraper",
        "namespace": "kubernetes-dashboard",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/dashboard-metrics-scraper",
        "uid": "932dc2d5-4675-11ea-952a-025000000001",
        "resourceVersion": "202570",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-03T11:08:58Z",
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "dashboard-metrics-scraper"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"dashboard-metrics-scraper\"},\"name\":\"dashboard-metrics-scraper\",\"namespace\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":8000,\"targetPort\":8000}],\"selector\":{\"k8s-app\":\"dashboard-metrics-scraper\"}}}\n"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "ports": [
          {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 8000,
            "targetPort": 8000
          }
        ],
        "selector": {
          "k8s-app": "dashboard-metrics-scraper"
        },
        "clusterIP": "10.106.158.177",
        "type": "ClusterIP",
        "sessionAffinity": "None"
      },
      "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {

        }
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
        "namespace": "kubernetes-dashboard",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/kubernetes-dashboard",
        "uid": "931a96eb-4675-11ea-952a-025000000001",
        "resourceVersion": "202558",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-03T11:08:58Z",
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"},\"name\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\",\"namespace\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":443,\"targetPort\":8443}],\"selector\":{\"k8s-app\":\"kubernetes-dashboard\"}}}\n"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "ports": [
          {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 443,
            "targetPort": 8443
          }
        ],
        "selector": {
          "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard"
        },
        "clusterIP": "10.108.57.147",
        "type": "ClusterIP",
        "sessionAffinity": "None"
      },
      "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {

        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: dashboard pod are deployed in there own namespace `kubernetes-dashboard` whats the output of `$ kubectl get pod --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard` ? are all pod up ?

Comment: also add output of below commands to the question `$ kubectl get deployments -A | grep -i dashboard` and `$ kubectl get service -A | grep -i dashboard`

Comment: @DT. Updated question. 
To check deployments and service it is throwing unknown shorthand flag: 'A' in -A

Comment: Clearly the dashboard pod has filed to install `kubernetes-dashboard-659f6797cf-8v45l   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff` can you check pod logs for what is failure cause !!

Comment: @DT. `kubectl get pods` shows no rescource found

Comment: kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443

Comment: Adding hint below on how to check logs of a failed pod.

Comment: Can you list all your system/dashboard pods ( `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` )  and provide details about your kubernetes environment?

Comment: Can you also post logs from dashboard pod? Do you have a metrics pod running as well?

Answer (score -1):

**Working dashboard application should list below resources in running sate**

```
$ kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard

NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-76585494d8-c6n5x   1/1     Running   0          136m
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-5996555fd8-wmc44        1/1     Running   0          136m

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.109.217.134   <none>        8000/TCP  136m
service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.108.201.245   <none>        443/TCP   136m

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           136m
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           136m

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-76585494d8   1         1         1       136m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-5996555fd8        1         1         1       136m
```

**Run describe command on failed pod and verify the events listed to find issue**

Example:

```
$ kubectl describe -n kubernetes-dashboard pod kubernetes-dashboard-5996555fd8-wmc44

Events:          <none>
```

Comment: My dashboard-metrics-scraper is not running.

Comment: Could it be because my Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6443 and not on 8443 ?